# Magento Color Swatch

Tags: magento, attributes

i have a question regarding the Color Swatch in Magento.

I have the next scenario:

3 Colors 3 sizes for each color. the sku is the same just adding 3 letters at the end.
Ex: XZ12345_RED, XZ12345_BLU, XZ12345_YEL

```
Product 1 Red Configurable / Contain Images only for Red / Visible Catalog/Search
   Product 1 Red S
   Product 1 Red M
   Product 1 Red L

Product 1 Blue Configurable / Contain Images only for Blue / Visible only on Search
   Product 1 Blue S
   Product 1 Blue M
   Product 1 Blue L

Product 1 Yellow Configurable / Contain Images only for Yellew / Visible only on Search
   Product 1 Yellow S
   Product 1 Yellow M
   Product 1 Yellow L
```

Now, im showing in catalog only the Red color.

My question is how can i get in product view "More colors" the 2 seconds colors?

My idea is to get the sku and short to 7 characters and then addfilterattribute sku and put the shorted sku there to show the others colors.

Anyone can push a bit and give me another idea or suggestion to get this done?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you use Amasty's Color Swatches pro. Because right now, Magento's default Color Swatches feature is kinda limited. :D

Answer (score 0):

I can give you Color Swatch Extension, if you want.

Comment: Will be great if you can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need Color Swatch extension for Magento and the best one is from Extensionsmall.com Check basic versions and you can start from this and then upgrade later to more advanced version: http://www.extensionsmall.com/magento-color-swatch.html